# Which algorithm or library can I use for duplicate Image detection on map tiles?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, tiles, mapbox

I am converting PNG images to 256x256 PNG dimension tiles.
I would like to detect nearly identical tiles (like blue water or white background tiles or gaps on floor plans) 
A lot of tiles cannot be distinguished by the eye but have nevertheless some different pixels so a md5 hash doesn't do the work...
what else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the spot offhand, but [TileMill](http://tilemill.org) does this and is open source (http://github.com/mapbox/tilemill). It may defer to [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org) for the de-dupe. One thing to keep in mind is that once you've determined a tile is a duplicate, you can also discount all tiles below it in the "pyramid" -- for example, a single tile is four tiles in the next zoom level down, and each of those is another four in the next zoom etc.

Comment: Found it - this is what you want: https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive.js

Comment: I see that github.com/mapbox/tilelive.js helps me with querying  iterating and copying tiles stored in a MBTiles backend ? But how does it help me with de-dupe? (my tiles are non-geo so maybe Mapnik is not an a option?)

Comment: De-dupe is happening here: https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive.js/blob/db41bbc26b4cb5c070e22bfbae2e30d45707b63e/lib/pyramidscheme.js#L31